# MYSQL subquery selection

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm having problems with subquery. This query displays a function that I need to perform the query I need

```
SELECT *,
open_hour_from - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeFrom, 
open_hour_to - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeTo,
GROUP_CONCAT(open_hour_day) AS days
FROM `open_hours` WHERE open_hour_connect_id = 2
GROUP BY timeFrom, timeTo
ORDER BY days
```

This are two functions

```
open_hour_from - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeFrom, 
open_hour_to - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeTo,
```

I know that subquery may return only one value. But how can I use timeFrom and timeTo variables? Should I put the in HAVING and how can I do that?

```
SELECT *,
     ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(open_hour_day) 
       FROM ` WHERE open_hour_connect_id = 2 
       GROUP BY timeFrom, timeTo ORDER BY days ) 
FROM connections
```

Comment: I edited your post so the second query was readable, but then I noticed that the subquery's from clause was incomplete. Was that intended?

Comment: Yes, this was intened, because I don't know where can I put two functions. But I think I got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you really want somthing like

```
SELECT c.*, sub.* 
FROM 
  connections c 
  INNER JOIN 
  (  
 SELECT *,
    open_hour_from - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeFrom, 
    open_hour_to - ((open_hour_day - 1) * 24 * 60) AS timeTo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(open_hour_day) AS days
    FROM `open_hours` WHERE open_hour_connect_id = 2
    GROUP BY timeFrom, timeTo
    ORDER BY days) sub
 ON c.days = sub.days
```